# Submit Spark Application on Kubernetes in Cluster mode : Configured service account doesn't have access

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I try to submit a Spark application to a Kubernetes cluster (Minikube).
When running my spark submit in client mode, everything goes well. 3 executors are created in 3 pods, and the code is executed. Here is my submit command :

```
[MY_PATH]/bin/spark-submit \
   --master k8s://https://[API_SERVER_IP]:8443 \
   --deploy-mode client \
   --name [Name] \
   --class [MyClass] \
   --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark:2.4.0 \
   --conf spark.executor.instances=3 \
   [PATH/TO/MY/JAR].jar
```

Now, I adapted it to run in cluster mode :

```
[MY_PATH]/bin/spark-submit \
   --master k8s://https://[API_SERVER_IP]:8443 \
   --deploy-mode cluster \
   --name [Name] \
   --class [MyClass] \
   --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark:2.4.0 \
   --conf spark.executor.instances=3 \
   local://[PATH/TO/MY/JAR].jar
```

This time, a driver pod is created as well as a driver service, and then the driver pod fail. On the Kubernetes I can see the following error :

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "spark-conf-volume" : configmap "sparkpi-1555314081444-driver-conf-map" not found
```

And in the pod logs I have the error :

```
Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. 
Service account may have been revoked. 
pods "sparkpi-1555314081444-driver" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default".
```

Here is the full stacktrace :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: External scheduler cannot be instantiated
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2794)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:493)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi$.main(SparkPi.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi.main(SparkPi.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86) 
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: GET at: https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/sparkpi-1555314081444-driver. Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. pods "sparkpi-1555314081444-driver" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default".
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.requestFailure(OperationSupport.java:470)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.assertResponseCode(OperationSupport.java:407)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:379)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:343)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:312)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:295)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:783)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:217)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:184)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator$$anonfun$1.apply(ExecutorPodsAllocator.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator$$anonfun$1.apply(ExecutorPodsAllocator.scala:55)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator.<init>(ExecutorPodsAllocator.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterManager.createSchedulerBackend(KubernetesClusterManager.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2788)
    ... 20 more
```

What should I do to make it work ?

Comment: Can you share the manifests you are using for deploying your application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to create an authorized service account: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#rbac

```
kubectl create serviceaccount spark
kubectl create clusterrolebinding spark-role --clusterrole=edit --serviceaccount=default:spark --namespace=default
```

And then pass it as a parameter to the submit

```
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark
```

Comment: I am trying to deploy spark to a different namespace, I have created the service account and given the `clusuterrolebinding` to spark-role, `clustrrole` as edit and mentioning the namespace that I wanted to. But while submitting the job I am getting the same Forbidden error. Any leads?

Comment: pass the namespace as a parameter while submitting the job
`--conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=<custom-namespace>`